# React DnD - Is it possible to only show the element being dragged in the drag preview, rather than also showing elements behind it?

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

Similar to this post here: [Drag and drop - The fixed element showing up on the drag image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62998874/drag-and-drop-the-fixed-element-showing-up-on-the-drag-image/70072533?noredirect=1#comment123869702_70072533)

Say for example, I have an element absolute positioned over a background image. If I drag and drop that element, the drag preview also shows the piece of the background image behind it. That makes for a not so smooth experience.

Is it possible to hide any background elements in the drag preview? Thanks!